# How do I make the tab row background of Chrome be *not* transparent?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7

The background behind my Chrome tabs is now transparent. I can't click the close [x] and I often see other Chrome Window's tabs behind it which is very confusing.

[image]

Comment: Questions about web browser functionality belong on [su].